# How can I analyze live data from webcam?

Tags: binary, webcam

I am going to be working on self-chosen project for my college networking class and I just had a couple questions to help get me started in the right direction.

My project will involve creating a new "physical" link over which data, in the form of text, will be transmitted from one computer to another.  This link will involve one computer with a webcam that reads a series of flashing colors (black/white) as binary and converts it to text.  Each series of flashes will simulate a packet of data.  I will be using OSX an the integrated webcam in a Macbook,  the flashing computer will either be windows or osx.

So my questions are: which programming languages or API's would be best for reading live webcam data and analyzing the color of a certain area as well as programming and timing the flashes?  Also, would I need to worry about matching the flash rate of the "writing" computer and the frame capture rate of the "reading" computer?

Thank you for any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: You may be interested in [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the frame capture rate, [Shannon sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) says that "perfect reconstruction of a signal is possible when the sampling frequency is greater than twice the maximum frequency of the signal being sampled". In other words if your flashing light switches 10 times per second, you need a camera of more than 20fps to properly capture that. So basically check your camera specs, divide by 2, lower the resulting a little and you have your maximum flashing rate.

Whatever can get the frames will work. If the light conditions in which the camera works are gonna be stable, and the position of the light on images is gonna be static then it is gonna be very very easy with checking the average pixel values of a certain area.

If you need additional image processing you should probably also find out about OpenCV (it has bindings to every programming language).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about language choice, I would recommend java. The Java Media Framework is great and easy to use. I have used it for capturing video from webcams in the past. Be warned, however, that everyone you ask will recommend a different language - everyone has their preferences!

What are you using as the flashing device? What kind of distance are you trying to achieve? Something worth thinking about is how are you going to get the receiver to recognise where within the captured image to look for the flashes. Some kind of fiducial marker might be necessary. Longer ranges will make this problem harder to resolve.

If you're thinking about shorter ranges, have you considered using a two-dimensional transmitter? (given that you're using a two-dimensional receiver, it makes sense) and maybe have a transmitter that shows a sequence of QR codes (or similar encodings) on a monitor?

You will have to consider some kind of error-correction encoding, such as a hamming code. While encoding would increase the data footprint, it might give you overall better bandwidth given that you can crank up the speed much higher without having to worry about the odd corrupt bit.

Some 'evaluation' type material might include you discussing the obvious security risks in using such a channel - anyone with line of sight to the transmitter can eavesdrop! You could suggest in your writeup using some kind of encryption, a block cipher in CBC would do, but would require a key-exchange prior to transmission, so you could think about public key encryption.